# is it possible to set foreign key in phpmyadmin while creating the table itself?

Tags: mysql

Can anybody say is it possible to add the foreign key while doing the table creation itself, I mean creating foreign key without using any queries.

My question is :
I can create two tables using query, like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
   id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   name CHAR(60) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
  );


CREATE TABLE shirt (
  id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  style ENUM('t-shirt', 'polo', 'dress') NOT NULL,
  color ENUM('red', 'blue', 'orange', 'white', 'black') NOT NULL,
  owner SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL REFERENCES person(id),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
 );
```

Is it possible for me to create the same using phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 1):

Of course

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE child (
    id INT, 
    parent_id INT,
    INDEX par_ind (parent_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) 
        REFERENCES parent(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

[Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Answer (score 0):

`Foreign key` is a column or a combination of columns that is used to establish and enforce a link between the data in two tables (TableA & TableB for example).

There's no problem in creating a TableB with a foreign key, as long as TableA, which contains the columns you want to link already exists.

As in the example below, you can create the FK, as long as the column P_Id exists in table Persons.

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
O_Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
OrderNo int NOT NULL,
P_Id int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Persons(P_Id) 
)
```